# Why is [object Casper].test undefined?

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I am evaluating CasperJS' testing API under Windows. Unfortunately, the test property of the Casper object is always undefined.

Running the following script prints "this.test is undefined":

```
phantom.casperPath = 'D:\\GitHubSources\\casperjs';
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '\\bin\\bootstrap.js');

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:56679/index.html', function(){
    this.echo('this.test is ' + this.test);
});

casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you seem using the 1.1 branch, which has backward uncompatible changes; as stated [in the branch changelog](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#important-changes--caveats):

> The Casper object won't be created with a `test` reference if not invoked using the [`casperjs test` command](http://casperjs.org/testing.html#casper-test-command), therefore the ability to run any test without calling it has been dropped. I know, get over it.

PS: I'm actually considering tagging the `master` branch as 2.0

Comment: NiKo, you're right, I accidentally used the master branch. Works fine with tag 1.0.0. Thank you for your great work!